# LESS merge variable names and get value

Tags: variables, merge, namespaces, less, mixins

I want to create a mixin that would return the value of a namespaced variable by merging of its arguments.

For see:

```
@namespace_thing: "some value";
@namespace_otherthing: "some other value";

@othernamespace_thing: "another value";
@othernamespace_otherthing: "again other value";
```

the mixin:

```
.monster(@namespace,@var){
 @tmp: ~"@{namespace}"+"_"+@{var};

 content: @tmp // That's what I just dont know.

}

#TESTSELECTOR{

.monster(namespace,thing); // would return 

    content: "some value";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do that is to use [variable name references](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names):

```css
@namespace_thing: "some value";

.monster(@namespace, @var) {
    @ref: '@{namespace}_@{var}';
    content: @@ref;
}

usage {
    .monster(namespace, thing);
}
```

Also see [mixins as functions](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature) if you need to return a value instead of assigning it to a predefined property.